# QWebView memory use

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qwebview

When I use multiple QWebView objects, I have noticed that after loading the pages and then deleting the object QWebView, the memory is not fully cleared.

Thus the program uses a large amount of extra memory. How can I clear the memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QWebView has static variables, which are cleaned up upon exiting the application very late during shutdown, thus QWebView seems to have memory leaks. I don't think though that these leaks accumulate during execution of an executable (though this is hard to prove!).

Unless you need JavaScript, Flash, CSS or something like that, you can replace QWebView with QTextBrowser, which is both faster and free of "static leaks".